# How can I check the variable whether it exists or not

Tags: javascript, variables

```
var a;
typeof(a);
//undefined

typeof(c);
//undefined

if(c) {}
//throw error
```

How can I know that `c` doesn't exist without `try` `catch`.

Update after marked duplicate:
`typeof initializedVariable` and `typeof notInitializedVariable` both will show 'undefined'. My question is to know whether the variable exists(initialized) or not.

Comment: `if(c !== undefined)` ?

Comment: What was the problem with the other similar questions (see list at right, you should have seen it when making the question) ?

Comment: Why don't you want a warning if you try to use a variable that doesn't exist?

Comment: `typeof initializedVariable` and `typeof notInitializedVariable` both will show 'undefined'. My question is to know whether the variable exists(initialized) or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof) operator.

```
 if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
     // variable is undefined
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't address the question (it is a bad q. though).

Comment: `typeof c === 'undefined'` is also `true`.